# Cannot join armatures without mesh detaching

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, edit-mode, transforms

I am trying to join two armatures and cannot get the meshes to stay in place. I've tried applying transformations and made sure there weren't any bones with the same name, but the meshes still detach. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you apply scale to the rig/armature after re-sizing the armature? If you don't apply scale (Ctrl+A) the mesh will not follow it. 
Or are you trying t o"join" them together? Ctrl+J.

Comment: I did that already, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you select armature A, then shift select Armature B, then press Ctrl J, they will be joined into a single armature called B; so you have to set your mesh constraints to look at armature B, not A.

[image]